# My android listview does not show last items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, listadapter

I have tested all i can from google, so. In the picture there are more wrong answers list which should be shown, but it's not showing.

[image]

I tried, **30dp or more bottompadding to listview** , **android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"** , **app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"** , **adding listview in scrollview** etc, but nothing is solving this problem. Please suggest something !

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.it.jumtech.adaptest.activity.ResultDetailActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:text="Result Detail"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_roll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Correct Answers"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_wrongscore" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_rightlist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="205dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label1"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wrong Answers"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lv_rightlist"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_wronglist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="205dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label2"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**list resource file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.it.jumtech.adaptest.activity.ResultDetailActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_qsn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Answer "
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_qsn"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_asnwer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/label1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_qsn"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/label2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Choosen "
android:textSize="16sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_asnwer"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_qsn"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_choosen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/label2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_qsn"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mark "
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_choosen"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_qsn"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_mark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/label3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_qsn"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
```

Comment: Do you mean to say listView isn't scrollable?

Comment: @RahulShukla yes you can say so.

Comment: Try removing unnecessary "+" from the ids specified in constraints, and re-work on your layout.

Comment: @RahulShukla working whole day, stuck with single problem .

Comment: If possible, please share the code sample so everyone can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two list view in one layout than you need to calculate list height programmatically and set to lists.
For this, answer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329419/merging-two-listviews-one-above-another-with-a-common-scroll?rq=1) can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are following is incorrect. To design such kind of view, you should create a nested `RecyclerView`. Inside the parent `RecyclerView` view, you should create another `recyclerView`. So the `adapter` of parent `RecyclerView` will have a child `recyclerView`. 
In the **adapter** class, you can inflate different view types based upon your requirement. Below is the dummy code for parent `Adapter` class for your help.

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case TYPE1:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_1, parent, false);
                return new ViewHolder1(view);
            case TYPE_DATA:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_2, parent, false);
                return new Viewholder2(view);

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("No match for found for" + viewType);
        }
    }



@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof Viewholder1) {
            viewholder1 = (Viewholder1) holder;
          }
        if (holder instanceof Viewholder2) {
            viewholder2 = (Viewholder2) holder;
        }
    }


    @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                //Based on certain condition, change your return type
               if (type1)
                 return viewType1;
               if(type2)
                 return viewType2;
                 ....        
}
```